# Why getting error when running 2 test in testing-library/react, NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, next.js, react-testing-library

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import ArticleListComponent from "../src/ui/components/pages/ArticleList";

test("render headline", async () => {
  render(<ArticleListComponent />);

  expect(screen.getByTestId("article-heading")).toHaveTextContent(
    "Content Articles"
  );
});

test("check add new button click", async () => {
  render(<ArticleListComponent />);
  const button = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /Add New/i });
  fireEvent.click(button);

  expect(screen.getByText("News")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I am getting this error when I run this code that has 2 tests.

**Error Message**
`A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --detectOpenHandles to find leaks. Active timers can also cause this, ensure that .unref() was called on them.`

I can run the test independently, like if I comment out the second test, then it runs perfectly. Same result if I comment out the first test.

If I use `npm run test --detectOpenHandles` then I don't get any error, but the terminal hangs and after around 2 minutes, it shows this error

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[48861:0x102d52000]   111487 ms: Mark-sweep 2035.9 (2060.8) -> 2032.0 (2076.8) MB, 1827.8 / 4.8 ms  (average mu = 0.087, current mu = 0.023) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
```

I tried putting test inside **describe**, still same issue

**Update**
I had some issues in my Component's useEffect where I was not handling the API call properly

Comment: Please provide the code for the component under test.

Comment: @juliomalves I have just a useEffect without any dependency in the ArticleListComponent component. And inside that useEffect I am doing an API call. It's just a normal Axios API call. I am getting the error for that API call. Nothing related to state update. If I don't call the API, it works fine. But I need to call the API.